# Different result on same code using toLocaleDateString

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set a date to my culture (fr-FR) using node and javascript. I found  a good method on mozilla website:

```
var event = new Date();

var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', options));
// Result is  "samedi 8 juin 2019"
```

It is working on the website (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleDateString)but when i use this code in my node server, the result is totally different:

`2019 M06 8, Sat`

What am i missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs by default only contains the en-US locale ([see here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8500)),
You can fix it by add [full-icu-npm](https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm) to dependency:

`npm install --save full-icu`

And then add flag to npm script:

```
For package.json:
{"scripts":{"start":"node --icu-data-dir=node_modules\\full-icu YOURAPP.js"}}
```

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "npm script"?

Comment: It's scripts property in your package.json

Comment: same behaviour after installing the package and changing package.json

Comment: {
  "name": "todolist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --icu-data-dir=node_modules\\full-icu index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "date-and-time": "^0.7.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "full-icu": "^1.3.0"
  }
}

Comment: It seems fine if you run your app by `npm start`, i can't guess the problem if i can't debug it, so please see this [document](https://techoverflow.net/2018/09/19/fixing-nodejs-intl-datetimeformat-not-formatting-properly-for-locales/)  (solution 2)

Comment: maybe that's the point... I m lauching using node index.js until now to launch my app. Am I supposed to change?

Comment: Yes, you should run `npm start` instead `node index.js` to launch your app :') try it